# alternative to finish()

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-finish

I read in the docs that one should avoid using finish() - but I don't really see a better alternative for this...

**I just like to know, if there is a better, cleaner way to do this...**

Many thanks

This is what I basically need to do:

```
MainActivity 
   -> Sub1Activity
      -> MySMSActivity
         -> send SMS
         -> handle if SMS was sent or not
            <- finish()
      <- finish()
(skip Sub1Activity)
MainActivity
```

The code in MainActivity:

```
this.myBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        doSub1Activity("xyz"); 
    }
});

public void doSub1Activity() {
    Intent i;
    i = new Intent(this, SUB1_screen.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

The code in Sub1Activity:

```
this.myBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       doMySMSActivity("xxx"); 
       finish();         //<- this is the 1. call to "finish" I am concerned about
    }
public void doMySMSActivity() {
    Intent i;
    i = new Intent(this, MySMSActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    }
```

The code in MySMSActivity:

```
private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
    {        
        String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
        String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

        PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                new Intent(SENT), 0);

        //---when the SMS has been sent---
        bRSMS_has_been_sent = new BroadcastReceiver(){
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {

                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    ...
                    break;
                default: 
                    break;
                }
                finish();  // another call to finish so the user continues with
                                       // MainActivity after SMS has been sent...
            }
        }; 

        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);        
    }
```

Comment: Can you link to the docs please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to call `finish()` multiple times. If you need to return to the main activity simply start it using an intent with the flags below. That will reuse the activity if it already exists.

`Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`

Comment: Just to clariy, in MySMSActivity I would startActivity(MainActivity) with the flags you mentioned? Will this cause the Sub1Activity and MySMSActivity to remain alive?

Comment: Yes. Generally you shouldn't be concerned about this though. You might want to release expensive resources `onPause()`, but other than that there is no problem if the activities are not finished.

Comment: Also, If I do not know which activity is the one I need to go back to (I just need to take these two off the stack and continue with whatever activity is on top, because Sub1Activity might have been called by another than MainActivity) would I then actually have to pass this activity all the way as a "delegate" so I know where to go back to? Is calling finish really that bad in this case?

Comment: You can pass it around or store is somewhere (application object, etc.). Generally, you should use intents to start activities, and not try to walk the backstack. You are, of course, free to use `startActivityForResult()` in combination with `finish()` to achieve a similar result.

Comment: Thanks for this! I guess then I will just stay with the calls to finish(), since there seems not to be a real reason to change this!

Answer (score 0):

Why  you make SMS sending itself an own activity?   It does not interact with user - just shell out your pending intent from Sub1Activity

Comment: ...because MySMSActivity does some other stuff in addition to just sending the SMS...